# Extern "C" constant value is not known in .cpp but works in .c

Tags: c++, keil

In C file

```
// f1.c
const uint8_t C_VAL=2;`
```

In C++ file I declare simple array

```
// f2.cpp
extern "C" const uint8_t C_VAL;
char charray[C_VAL];
```

> Build output:
>    `#259: constant value is not known`

There was not any errors when I link extern in .C

```
// f2.c
extern const uint8_t C_VAL;
char charray[C_VAL];
```

Works fine.

Seems the problem is with linkage. Is it possible to fix, how? Is this problem only in MDK-ARM or other compilers have too?

Comment: Where exactly do you declare `char charray[C_VAL];` ? Inside a function our outside of functions `?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Why do you expect them to have the same features?

Comment: If you are using *gcc*, you can probably use `-std=gnu++11` or something, to enable extension to support for variable length arrays on C++ code.

Comment: @Olaf, this is one of the design objectives of Stroustrup when designing the  C++ language, the usability of C code from C++.  This is an extremely simple example that shows something that should work.   So I think your comment is out of scope here.  I upvote and follow you in many questions we share, but I cannot do this time.

Comment: @LuisColorado: That might have been true for pre-standard C++ and ancient C90, resp. historic K&R-C. Especially the `const` qualifier has different semantics in both languages, not to mention other incompatibilities. Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics. And just using some C library would make any question a C question! Reading and comparing the standards helps! Re. what Stroustrup once wrote: Linus Torvalds once wrote that Linux would never be ported to anything other than x86 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C supports variable length arrays (since C99, but only optionally since C11. Some earlier compilers support them as a language extension), so the value of `C_VAL` doesn't need to be known at the time `f2.c` is compiled and so there isn't a problem.

C++ doesn't support variable length arrays (except some compilers support them as a language extension), so the value of `C_VAL` must be known at the time `f2.cpp` is compiled. Since it is merely declared, its value is not known and that is why the compiler shows you the quoted error. The value remains unknown until the object files of `f2.cpp` and `f1.c` are linked together.

Solution: Either use a language that supports VLA (such as C99), or a compiler that supports VLA as an extension (see the manual of your compiler whether it supports it, and how to enable the support) or define the array with a length that is known at compile time.

Comment: I'd add, that value *can't* be known at compile time usually, because the dynamic library (or whatever) where `C_VAL` is defined can change.